# App Crashes on Adding Google Play Services library in Cocos2d-x V3.0 Android project

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, google-play-services

I'm trying to add Google Play Services library in my Cocos2d-x V3.0 project to integrate admobe banner ads. I'm following this tutorial to integrate ads

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/User_Tutorial-Integrate_AdMob

but when I add following lines of code in AndroidManifest ,

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

app crashes with ActivityNotFound message , following appear in logcat

[image]

To Include Google Play Services Library , I followed these steps :

> 1- Imported library from my sdk folder
>   “ANDROID_SDK_HOME\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib”
>
> 2- Add version.xml in my res/values folder
>
> 3- Add reference of Google Play Services library in my project

I've also tried by directly adding Google play library version  in Menifest and copying library into currect working directory also but nothing worked for me.